# How to Use a Dropbox Datastore Observer in Swift

Tags: swift, dropbox-api

I think I managed to convert my Dropbox Datastore observer code from Objective-C to Swift, but I just wanted to confirm since I'm getting some `nil` values back when the observer fires.

Does this look right for an account info observer?

```
weak var account = DBAccountManager.sharedManager().linkedAccount

account?.addObserver(self, block: {
  let info = account?.info
  println(info?.displayName)
})
```

That `println` bit is returning nothing. I'm not entirely confident that I have converted the block to a closure correctly.

Has anyone else tried Datastore observers in Swift yet? Is this syntax correct?

Comment: why is `account` a `weak var`? I dont know the dropbox api at all, but it looks like `account` has most likely been released by the time `let info = account?.info` is executed, setting it to `nil`

Comment: Are you sure that `account` isn't nil at this point? It's usually helpful to check `if let account = account?` since this observer can be triggered by an account being unlinked (and thus, no more linked account).

Comment: That's a good idea, Leah. I'll be sure to wrap it in an `if let`. Thanks.